# Android: how can I only perform an action once and not again after screen rotation?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to send tracking data to google analytics for every screen view. Currently I am sending this hit in the activities onStart(), but when the screen rotates it sends another hit for the same screen. How should I implement my screen tracking to avoid sending multiple screen views every time the user rotates his device?

Note: I understand why multiple hits are being sent but I would like a way to track every screen in my application without sending multiple hits when a rotation occurs.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should intercept the Activity rotation and avoid Activity recreation implementing onConfiChanged in your activity and declaring in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
  ...
/>
```

or alternatively you can save in savedInstanceState that you already sent the data and in next onActivity created you can retrieve this info and avoid sending :D

Hope it helps.

Comment: Question about the savedInstanceState implementation, what if the user selects the back button and goes to a previous screen? I want that to be tracked.

Comment: If the user click back button in ActivityA than user goes again into ActivityA...savedInstanceState will be null because the activity was finished (destroyed) with back button and you can track ActivityA again.

Comment: Okay makes sense, but doesn't ActivityA also get destroyed on rotation?

Comment: You will find the state after configChanged using savedInstanceState Bundle

Comment: It did not solve my particular case, but I think it could be helpful to others. It certainly got me on the right path to finding my solution. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Limiting screen rotation just because you don't want to send tracking info again isn't a good idea. `savedInstance` should be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public bool variable and check against it for if the analytics have been sent previously.

Answer (score 0):

I added a helper class to handle my tracking.  The class does some additional checks to test for rotation.  If we are on the same screen and the orientation is different then we have a rotation and the screen should not be tracked.  If the screens are different then we want to track the new screen.  I'm simplifying my solution and it certainly doesn't handle all the edge cases, but hopefully you can get a better idea on where to start for a potential solution.